# Could not find a declaration file for module - inherit types, mixed JS and TS projects

Tags: reactjs, typescript, intellisense, monorepo, tsconfig

I am configuring React monorepo and we have components and utils libraries that are both shared Then we have apps that use these.

The problem is, majority of components and utils is written in plain javascript, we have now started rewriting them in typescript but that takes a while so we need to be able to use both, the newly written TS components and also the old JS ones. Now the problem is when I create new  react project without typescript, I can easily import the shared components, use them and get intellisense help and types (if they are written in ts already or atleast get some generated types for that plain js ones). [working intellisense and types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYAHu.png)

However, when I initialize new React project with typescript (standard Vite setup). I get this error on imported components [error importing components in React+TS project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3WEC.png)

Here is my tsconfig.json for TS React projects:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es5",
      "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
      "allowJs": true,
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "strict": true,
      "module": "esnext",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
      "isolatedModules": true,
      "noEmit": true,
      "jsx": "react-jsx",
      "declaration": true,
    },
    "include": ["src"],
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
    ]
  }
```

Components library babel config:

```
    module.exports = {
    presets: [
        [
            "@babel/preset-typescript",
            {
                targets: {
                    node: "current",
                },
            },
        ],
        [
            "@babel/preset-react",
            {
                isTsx: true,
            },
        ],
    ],
};
```

And components library webpack config:

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  entry: {
    index: { import: "./index.js" },
  },
  externals: {
    react: "react",
    "react-dom": "react-dom",
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"],
  },
  plugins: [new MiniCssExtractPlugin()],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        //test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  output: {
    filename: "components.bundle.min.js",
    library: "webclientappsComponents",
    libraryTarget: "umd",
    umdNamedDefine: true,
    clean: true,
  },
};
```

I have tried:

- setting allowJs and checkJs in tsconfig - no effect
- create typings.d.ts file in root directory and declaring module "*" - this solves the error and I can use the components, but then I no longer have types and IntelliSense - I only have this [imported module without types and intellisense](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvT4Z.png)

I don't want to manually declare all these types, Is there any way to make It work just like It works for me in non-TS project?

Comment: It seems like you are using absolute path but in the tsconfig.json, there is no configuration which is related to absolute path.

Comment: compilerOptions.baseUrl : ".", compilerOptions.paths : { "@webclientapps/*" : "./src/*" }. Also, are you using webpack? or vite put alias : { "@webclientapps/* : "./src/*" } <- I'm not sure checking it about absolute path.

Comment: @HumanoidMk.12 this seems to have no effect. Yes we are using webpack & babel to build the components and utils libraries